# Match records immediately before and after time range

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

My objective is to join two data tables based on time with `dplyr` or `data.table`, specifically to get the record immediately before and immediately after an event.

In the example data, the events in this case are scooter trips.  Below are four trips - two taken by scooter 1 and two by scooter 2.

```
> testScooter
                 start                 end id
1: 2018-01-18 22:19:13 2018-01-18 22:26:31  1
2: 2018-01-18 23:29:22 2018-01-18 23:37:53  1
3: 2018-01-18 00:22:02 2018-01-18 00:29:21  2
4: 2018-01-18 00:37:52 2018-01-18 01:06:53  2
```

In a separate table are records spaced at nearly equal intervals apart. The `id`s match and the scooter is marked `no` when a trip is underway.

```
> intervals
   id                time available charge
1   1 2018-01-18 21:31:07       yes     83
2   1 2018-01-18 21:41:07       yes     83
3   1 2018-01-18 21:51:07       yes     83
4   1 2018-01-18 22:01:07       yes     83
5   1 2018-01-18 22:11:07       yes     83
6   1 2018-01-18 22:21:07        no     83
7   1 2018-01-18 22:31:07       yes     81
8   1 2018-01-18 22:41:08       yes     81
9   1 2018-01-18 22:51:08       yes     81
10  1 2018-01-18 23:01:08       yes     81
11  1 2018-01-18 23:11:08       yes     81
12  1 2018-01-18 23:21:11       yes     81
13  1 2018-01-18 23:31:07        no     81
14  1 2018-01-18 23:41:09       yes     79
15  1 2018-01-18 23:51:07       yes     79
16  2 2018-01-18 00:01:06       yes     84
17  2 2018-01-18 00:11:06       yes     84
18  2 2018-01-18 00:21:06       yes     84
19  2 2018-01-18 00:31:05       yes     80
20  2 2018-01-18 00:41:06        no     80
21  2 2018-01-18 00:51:06        no     80
22  2 2018-01-18 01:01:06        no     80
23  2 2018-01-18 01:11:05       yes     80
24  2 2018-01-18 01:21:05       yes     80
25  2 2018-01-18 01:31:05       yes     80
```

The output I am trying to produce is the following.

```
> output
                 start                 end id startCharge endCharge
1: 2018-01-18 22:19:13 2018-01-18 22:26:31  1          83        81
2: 2018-01-18 23:29:22 2018-01-18 23:37:53  1          81        79
3: 2018-01-18 00:22:02 2018-01-18 00:29:21  2          84        80
4: 2018-01-18 00:37:52 2018-01-18 01:06:53  2          80        80
```

Any suggestions on how to match on nearest time before and after a time range would be helpful, maybe by using `lubridate::new_interval()` or `roll='nearest'` from the `data.table` package but I am not sure where to begin.

```
# Here is the sample data

library(data.table)

testScooter <- setDT(
structure(list(start = structure(c(1516313953, 1516318162, 1516234922, 
1516235872), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), end = structure(c(1516314391, 
1516318673, 1516235361, 1516237613), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), id = c(1, 1, 2, 2)), .Names = c("start", "end", "id"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))

intervals <- 
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    time = structure(c(1516311067, 1516311667, 1516312267, 1516312867, 
    1516313467, 1516314067, 1516314667, 1516315268, 1516315868, 
    1516316468, 1516317068, 1516317671, 1516318267, 1516318869, 
    1516319467, 1516233666, 1516234266, 1516234866, 1516235465, 
    1516236066, 1516236666, 1516237266, 1516237865, 1516238465, 
    1516239065), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    available = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", 
    "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
    "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes"
    ), charge = c(83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 
    81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 79L, 79L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L)), .Names = c("id", "time", "available", 
"charge"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How is the `available` column used when generating the result?

Comment: it is in fact not relevant at all to the result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**New answer:**

You can do this with a double rolling join:

```
testScooter[, startCharge := intervals[testScooter, on = .(id, time = start), roll = Inf, x.charge]
            ][, endCharge := intervals[testScooter, on = .(id, time = end), roll = -Inf, x.charge]][]
```

which gives the desired result:

> ```
>                  start                 end id startCharge endCharge
> 1: 2018-01-18 23:19:13 2018-01-18 23:26:31  1          83        81
> 2: 2018-01-19 00:29:22 2018-01-19 00:37:53  1          81        79
> 3: 2018-01-18 01:22:02 2018-01-18 01:29:21  2          84        80
> 4: 2018-01-18 01:37:52 2018-01-18 02:06:53  2          80        80
> ```

What this does:

- `roll = Inf` looks for the last observation in `intervals` before `start`
- `roll = -Inf` looks for the first observation in `intervals` after `end`

See also the *Note* about why the new answer is better.

**Old answer:**

```
testScooter[intervals, on = .(id, start = time), roll = -Inf, startCharge := i.charge
            ][intervals, on = .(id, end = time), roll = Inf, endCharge := i.charge][]
```

**Note:**

As @Frank noted [here on Github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2022), `data.table` returns the last match in `i` when there are multiple matches, which is the case for the old answer. See the following output when the code is run with `verbose = TRUE`:

```
> testScooter[intervals, on = .(id, start = time), roll = -Inf, startCharge := i.charge, verbose = TRUE][]
Calculated ad hoc index in 0 secs
Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
Detected that j uses these columns: startCharge,i.charge 
Assigning to 16 row subset of 4 rows
                 start                 end id startCharge
1: 2018-01-18 22:19:13 2018-01-18 22:26:31  1          83
2: 2018-01-18 23:29:22 2018-01-18 23:37:53  1          81
3: 2018-01-18 00:22:02 2018-01-18 00:29:21  2          84
4: 2018-01-18 00:37:52 2018-01-18 01:06:53  2          80
```

Although this behavior doesn't lead to any problems in this example, it is less efficient and could possibly lead to unintended results. See this example (courtesy to @Frank):

```
> data.table(a = 1:2)[data.table(a = c(2L, 2L), v = 3:4), on=.(a), v := i.v, verbose = TRUE][]
Calculated ad hoc index in 0 secs
Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
Detected that j uses these columns: v,i.v 
Assigning to 2 row subset of 2 rows
   a  v
1: 1 NA
2: 2  4
```

The new answer is therefore the better option.

---

Used data:

```
testScooter <- structure(list(start = structure(c(1516313953, 1516318162, 1516234922, 1516235872), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
                              end = structure(c(1516314391, 1516318673, 1516235361, 1516237613), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
                              id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)),
                         .Names = c("start", "end", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
setDT(testScooter)

intervals <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                            time = structure(c(1516311067, 1516311667, 1516312267, 1516312867, 1516313467, 1516314067, 1516314667, 1516315268, 1516315868, 1516316468, 1516317068, 1516317671, 1516318267, 1516318869, 1516319467, 1516233666, 1516234266, 1516234866, 1516235465, 1516236066, 1516236666, 1516237266, 1516237865, 1516238465, 1516239065), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                            available = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes"), 
                            charge = c(83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 79L, 79L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L)),
                       .Names = c("id", "time", "available", "charge"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
setDT(intervals)
```

Comment: shouldn't the second brackets contain  `[intervals, on = .(id, end = time), roll = Inf, endCharge := i.charge]` ?

Comment: @the_darkside yes & fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data.table` non-equi to look up the nearest `startCharge` and `endCharge` as follows:

```
setDT(testScooter)
setDT(intervals)

testScooter[, startCharge := intervals[testScooter, .SD[, charge[.N], by=.(id, start)], on=.(id, time < start)]$V1]
testScooter[, endCharge := intervals[testScooter, .SD[, charge[1L], by=.(id, end)], on=.(id, time > end)]$V1]
```

Explanation for `startCharge`:

For the inner square brackets:

```
intervals[testScooter, .SD[, charge[.N], by=.(id, start)], on=.(id, time < start)]
```

You are doing a non-equi join such that `intervals`' id matches `testScooter`'s `id` and `time` in `intervals` are before `start` in `testScooter`.

And `.SD[, charge[.N], by=.(id, start)]` groups by `id` and `start` and return the latest `intervals`' `time` before each group's `start`.

Similarly for `endCharge`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the non-R (lame) solution :

```
#Convert to data table
testScooter <- data.table(testScooter)
intervals <- data.table(intervals)

#Dummy data frame to store the results which we will finally 
chargeDF <- data.frame(startCharge = numeric(),endCharge = numeric())

#Loop for each Unique ID
for( i in unique(intervals$id)){
  newScooter <- testScooter[id == i,]
  newintervals <- intervals[id == i,]
  #Check if start time in intervals DF less than time in testScooter
  tempStartList <- lapply(newScooter[,start], function (x) { newintervals[,time] < x})
  #Check if end time in intervals DF greater than time in testScooter
  tempEndList <- lapply(newScooter[,end], function (x) { newintervals[,time] > x})

#Loop through each row for a particular ID  
  for( j in 1:nrow(newScooter)){
    #Find the value just before the condition becomes false
    scharge <- tail(newintervals$charge[tempStartList[[j]]],1)
    #Find the value just after the condition becomes true
    echarge <- head(newintervals$charge[tempEndList[[j]]],1)

    #Bind the results to the dummy df created earlier
    chargeDF <- rbind(chargeDF,data.frame(startCharge = scharge,endCharge = echarge))
  }
}

output <- cbind(testScooter, chargeDF)
```